# Generate same random number each time when controller loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have Icon with me and one scope.id and I am assigning different color code each time with Icon .
Suppose

```js
angular.module('myAppp').controller('myCtrl',function(){
    scope.id=[0,1,2,3];
    //generate random number
    $scope.Icon=[];
    for(i=0;i<scope.id.length;i++) {
        var ran= Math.floor( Math.random()*255)+$scope.id[i];
        $scope.Icon.push(ran);
    }   
});
```

HTML

```html
<div ng-repeat='id in id'>
    <span style="background-color:rgb({{$scope.Icon[$index]}},255,255)">{{id}}</span>
</div>
```

so I want that when I will reload my page again it should get same color again but now it will return different color because of Math.random()

Please suggest me or guide me because I am new.

Comment: store the combination in localstorage and call the function only if the value is not found in localstorage

Comment: local storage would be on single machine ,If user would change the amchine It will give generate again different number. ???

Comment: Then you should store stuff, in some server side implementation. Have a user preferences table on your server, storing all such details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) to store the current value.

Each time you **load** the page check if there is a previously stored cookie, if not, you assign a random value and store it in a **new** cookie.

Everytime the color is changed, you must assign the value to the cookie, so each time the user loads or reloads the page, if there is already a value, you set the color to the one in the cookie.

Here is an example on how to use cookies in angularjs:
http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2014/11/angularjs-cookie-example.html/

Comment: What if user will use different machine next time??

Comment: @ShubhamNigam that way you should store the color in the server side (database). You need to consider the cost / benefit, because that operation is a lot more heavy, each time the user changes the color, you need to send it to your server, where you store it.

Comment: Toni ,all the way you are absolutely right but server side storage would a problem for my scenario because my application is in client side application where I am using google drive for storage..

You can help me with this .. some how I found random values same on every page load but problem is ..it is not gerating color with more brightness..
Fiddle:-
http://fiddle.jshell.net/xopddsxp/3/

Answer (score 0):

> The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user

From [JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Use pregenerated array of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of dynamic color change on page load: http://fiddle.jshell.net/xopddsxp/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myAppp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat='id in id'>
        <span style="background-color:rgb({{Icon[$index]}},{{Icon[$index +1]}},{{Icon[$index + 2]}})">{{id}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("myAppp", []).controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $http){
     $scope.id = [0,1,2,3]; //generate random number
     $scope.Icon=[];
     for(i=0; i < $scope.id.length; i++){  
       var ran= Math.floor( Math.random()*255)+$scope.id[i];
       $scope.Icon.push(ran);
     }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for fiddle  but on reload page it is generating different colors where I want same color with  every page load.

Comment: If u look over the another answers ,I have mentioned the same thing..

By the way What if user is operating on other machine???

Comment: have you check the another link, where you can store value is web DB. if user is operating on other machine then you have to manage these value in server side.

Comment: thanks for your valueable reply but the thing is I want to do it on client machine only .As I am searching for it from a long time .
I have reached to some milestone that I want to Share and  i hope u will like it..
Fiddle:-http://jsfiddle.net/zFbfE/29/

I am not posting it as a answer because it doesnot contains completely different contrast colors.

If you can improve this please share and Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear to me. please improve your question.